# How to add new text,but unable to modify old text

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

how do I set permission for a file on Windows such as .docx so that network user can **ONLY** add new text into the file.They must **NOT** be able to edit the old text,but the **CAN** add new ones.

What I'm trying to do is I want Users from different PC to be able to add more information in the .docx without deleting the old content so that hackers or just some clumsy staff won't be able to delete the previous content.

I already created a permission to block from creating any file in the save folder so that staff won't create unnecessary documents since the staff here just LOVE stacking and duplicating their work.

If this is possible please teach me sensei.Thank you

P.S I tried setting Create folder/append data but it doesn't work.Please also explain to me what exactly it does.

Answer (score 1):

this is fairly trivial in word by simply controlling the regions.  with a text file you need either an app or script that opens the file with FILE_APPEND_DATA access, and set permissions on the file with append only.  for more details in word, ask on superuser.

Answer (score 0):

This [could be do-able in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605053/append-only-file), however if only for certain filesystems. I'm not sure this is achievable in any windows-based file systems. And even if it were I'm not sure it's achievable for the `.docx` file type since when you modify those files to just append text, it's more than just the last bytes of the file that are edited. In short, I don't think it's possible, however I would like to be proven wrong on this!

Perhaps you could look into some 3rd party software to help you do this, though it may no longer be `.docx`

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I'll edit my question to notify that I want it for Window.As for 3rd party programs,I'd like to prevent myself from using that.I'm implementing this method for a company,and downloading a 3rd party program might cause some error like virus etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do this with Linux, you need special filesystems that overcome the permission limitations.